# Sum up totals whose date falls within the same month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my A2 cell I have this: `01/01/2015` and then I have this equation:

```
=SUMIFS(Tracker!A:A,Tracker!B:B, "Payment",Tracker!D:D, ">="&DATE(2015, 01, 1),Tracker!D:D, "<"&DATE(2015, 02, 1))
```

I would like to take out the hardcoding of the date in the above equation, and rather than saying "Is it greater or equal to the first of January and less than the first of February" I would rather say: "Sum up the entries which fall within the month and year in A2".

This is the code I know to get the month and year from A2:

```
MONTH(A2) & YEAR (A2)
```

How do I make the SUMIFS work to add up the totals which fall within that same month and year of A2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the date in A2 to supply the [MONTH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MONTH-function-579A2881-199B-48B2-AB90-DDBA0EBA86E8) and [YEAR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/YEAR-function-C64F017A-1354-490D-981F-578E8EC8D3B9) into the [DATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-B91BEF00-4B5B-4EE0-B80E-06E68B1DFF29).

```
=SUMIFS(Tracker!A:A,Tracker!B:B, "Payment",Tracker!D:D, ">="&DATE(YEAR(A2), MONTH(A2), 1),Tracker!D:D, "<"&DATE(YEAR(A2), MONTH(A2)+1, 1))
```

Alternately, combining the [EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) with the [EOMONTH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EOMONTH-function-7314FFA1-2BC9-4005-9D66-F49DB127D628) could easily generate the end-of-month for the current date and one month previous.

Answer (score 0):

A little shorter:

```
=SUMIFS(Tracker!A:A,Tracker!B:B,"Payment",Tracker!D:D,">="&A2,Tracker!D:D,"<="&EOMONTH(A2,0))
```

Though I personally prefer to avoid the `>=` and `<=` combinations so would myself choose *two* cells, one with say 31 Dec 14 and another (say A3) that either calculated 1 Feb 15 (say `=EOMONTH(A2,1)+1`) or in which I entered that date, then the bigger formula is slightly tidier:

```
=SUMIFS(Tracker!A:A,Tracker!B:B,"Payment",Tracker!D:D,">"&A2,Tracker!D:D,"<"&A3)
```

One problem with the likes of 'less than or equal to' a date is that if the date has a time component, say noon - which may not be on display, then that can edge such a comparison to be outside the limit.